How to force sort order of records based on multiple columns
I have a query that returns the following data



ID
Col1
Col2




1
Val
Val


2
Val_1
Val


3
Val_1
Val_1


4
Val
Val_1


5
Val
Val



My organization wants this data ordered in a very specific way. They want any records with a "Val_1" value in either Col1 or Col 2 to be sorted to the bottom, UNLESS that record has a non-Val_1 value in the other column.
I followed the tutorial in this link to force records to the bottom based on ONE column, which produced the following results:
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Col1 = 'Val_1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC




ID
Col1
Col2




1
Val
Val


5
Val
Val


4
Val
Val_1


3
Val_1
Val_1


2
Val_1
Val



However, since Record with ID 2 has a Val for Col2 and not a Val_1, the Organization would want that Record to not go to the bottom. Thus, the desired result would be:



ID
Col1
Col2




1
Val
Val


5
Val
Val


4
Val
Val_1


2
Val_1
Val


3
Val_1
Val_1



Any tips on how to proceed will be greatly appreciated.

So why can you not add a second clause to your ORDER BY?

Can your stated requirement "records with a 'Val_1' value in either Col1 or Col 2 to be sorted to the bottom, UNLESS that record has a non-Val_1 value in the other column." be restated as "records with a 'Val_1' value in both Col1 or Col 2 to be sorted to the bottom"?  If so, then perhaps what you need is ORDER BY CASE WHEN Col1 = 'Val_1' AND Col2 = 'Val_1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC.

What REAL values do you have for Val van Val_1? Or are they are really different texts (or numbers), and for obfuscation replaced by Val ?

It is not clear to me what order you want. First rows without Val_1, then rows with one Val_1, then rows with two Val_1? And the order of the rows inside each of these three groups doesn't matter?

This assumes that Col1 has priority over Col2, if this is incorrect, just reverse the Col1 and Col2 references in the ORDER BY clause.
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID int, Col1 varchar(10), Col2 varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(1, 'Val', 'Val'),
(2, 'Val_1', 'Val'),
(3, 'Val_1', 'Val_1'),
(4, 'Val', 'Val_1'),
(5, 'Val', 'Val')

SELECT * FROM @t
    ORDER BY 
               CASE WHEN Col1 = 'Val_1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
             , CASE WHEN Col2 = 'Val_1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
             , Col1
             , Col2

This gives the following results...

note: the order of IDs 1 and 5 is arbitrary as both rows have the same Col1 and Col2 values. You could fix this by adding , ID to the end of the ORDER BY

Or maybe ...CASE WHEN Col1 = 'Val_1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Col2 = 'Val_1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END... And the ELSE clauses are useless, you could just remove them.

you can use caseand in operator in your order by like this
select *
from   table1 t
order by case when 'Val_1' in (Col1, Col2) then 1 end,
         Col1,
         Col2

See this dbFiddle
The outcome is



ID
Col1
Col2




1
Val
Val


5
Val
Val


4
Val
Val_1


2
Val_1
Val


3
Val_1
Val_1




What I have understood that when col1 and col2 both have val_1 then that should be at the bottom else if col1=val_1 then that should second last else if col2=val_1 then that should be third last.
you can try this,
Declare @fakeid decimal(6,1)=99999

select id,col1,col2
from
(
Select id,col1,col2,case when (col1='Val_1' and col2='Val_2') then @fakeid when col1='Val_1'  then @fakeid-(id+0.1) 
when col2='Val_1'  then @fakeid-(id)
else id end as New_ID
 from table1
)t4
order by New_ID

Also tomorrow requirement can change and become more complicated,more logic can be added to SORT data.In this case we can create seperate temp table or table variable for priority and update new_id
